# .NET Studio when design is ok , but after run app object on form is sliding

Tags: c#, .net, windows

In design mod the objects on the form are OK, but on runtime the objects on the form are smaller. How can I fix this problem ?

photo in design mode:
[image: photo in design mode]

photo after run application:
[image: [photo after run application]

Answer (score 0):

just add more height so if they became smaller they will look just like what you want :D

Comment: why did you downvoted my answer it is a solution :D 
what ?